# How to view the complete multidimensional array in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, jupyter, mnist

I'm completely new to this so I'd be grateful if someone could help out.

Is there any way i could view the complete multidimensional array in Jupyter notebook? I'm trying to work with the MNIST dataset.

[Please click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRlkf.png)

[This is how I want to view it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eyjl.png)

I need to view the entire array. Any help??

Comment: Please include all code as text and not as an image.

Comment: What's the shape of the array?  `numpy` starts using `...` when the number of elements goes over 1000.  That can be changed, but are you sure you want to?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, the number has exceeded 1000. I'd like to view it that way

Comment: You could view multiple slices.